# Customer Community Enhanced Email sObject type 'EmailMessage' is not supported

Tags: customer-community, enhanced-emails

I am trying to set up a Customer Community with Salesforce.

This is an Enterprise trial org with Enhanced Email enabled.

Internal users can see Related List 'Files' just fine.

The Community Users see this error in the Related List instead:

`sObject type 'EmailMessage' is not supported`

Since i can't actually assign permissions on this `EmailMessage` object, how can i enable the users in the portal to see case attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce support advised that we need to enable `Email-to-Case` feature for the related lists to work in the Community.